Franco Brezzi's didactic paper on the Inf-Sup condition
I am trying to recover the title of a very didactic paper by Franco Brezzi in which he explains the Inf-Sup condition with a very simple case. As I recall, it was a simple Laplacian equation in 1D whose solution was a second order polynomial.
Thanks in advance for refreshing my memory

I believe you are thinking of
"A discourse on the stability conditions for mixed finite element formulations" by Franco Brezzi and Klaus-Jürgen Bathe, published in Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering
Volume 82, Issues 1–3, September 1990, Pages 27-57.
Edit: I asked a friend of mine, he suggested that Boffi, Brezzi, Fortin "Mixed Finite Element Methods and Application" Section 5.2.4 might also be the source.

Dear Abdullah, you are absolutely right: this is the paper by Brezzi and Bathe, specifically the 4th section, which deals with the example I mentioned in my question.
Thank you very much !

@NicolasTardieu Happy to be able to help :)
